# NetTrain with External GPU?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, hardware, gpu

I'd like to use the new Neural Networks functionalities in v11 on my Macbook Pro, unfortunately, most macs do not have the supported Nvidia cards. However, there is the option for using an external E-GPUs.

Before purchasing I wanted to know if anyone has tried and succeeded in setting up this configuration? That is, getting Mathematica's NetTrain functionality to works using an external GPU.

**Updates:**

- I would rather use a remote kernel in AWS, but kernel tunneling broke in v11.1.
- I've heard connecting GPUs to OSX through a Thunderbolt port was a very fickle thing on OSX 10.12, but 10.13 has more robust support for this.

Comment: [How-To-Guide: External GPU on OSX - how to use CUDA on your Mac](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1085633)